# не могу обновить через консоль node.js ver. 8.17.0 до актуальной

Tags: node.js, npm

Всем привет! Уже опробовал абсолютно все варианты с этих ваших интернетов, начиная от:

```
npm update npm -g
```

и заканчивая, банальным прокси:

```
npm set http-proxy <proxy>
```

А все это ради vue.js

Спасибо за Ваше внимание!

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Какие-то ошибки вылазят или что?

Comment: Выходила ошибка

ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v8.17.0
You'll need to upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

после полного удаления и переустановки все заработало, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

Помогло полное удаление node.js и npm